# Pushing files to unc path(remote) in git

Tags: git

I have my PC and remote folder on UNC path (lets say `*\\10.30.1.15\GitRepositories\MyApp*`).

I have Git installed both in my pc and remote.
What I did is ran `git init` on UNC path and at `C:/GitRepositories/MyApp`.

Now I add a file at `C:/GitRepositories/MyApp` and ran the following commands.

```
git add .
git commit -m 'initial commit'
git remote add origin \\10.30.1.15\GitRepositories\MyApp
```

Now when I run *git push origin master*, I am getting:

```
C:\GitRepositories\MyApp>git push origin master
fatal: '\10.30.1.15\GitRepositories\MyApp.git' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

The UNC path is accessible for all users. Means shared with everyone for now.

Update: After updating the path path by escaping now I am getting,

```
C:\....>git init
Initialized empty Git repository in C:/..../.git/

C:\....>git remote add origin \\\\10.30.1.15\\GitRepositories\\MyApp

C:\....>git add .

C:\....>git commit -m 'intial'
[master (root-commit) 6870ea2] 'intial'
 1 file changed, 0 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
 create mode 100644 test.txt

C:\....>git push origin master
Counting objects: 3, done.
Writing objects: 100% (3/3), 207 bytes | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 3 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: error: refusing to update checked out branch: refs/heads/master
remote: error: By default, updating the current branch in a non-bare repository
remote: error: is denied, because it will make the index and work tree inconsistent
remote: error: with what you pushed, and will require 'git reset --hard' to match
remote: error: the work tree to HEAD.
remote: error:
remote: error: You can set 'receive.denyCurrentBranch' configuration variable to
remote: error: 'ignore' or 'warn' in the remote repository to allow pushing into
remote: error: its current branch; however, this is not recommended unless you
remote: error: arranged to update its work tree to match what you pushed in some
remote: error: other way.
remote: error:
remote: error: To squelch this message and still keep the default behaviour, set
remote: error: 'receive.denyCurrentBranch' configuration variable to 'refuse'.
To \\\\10.30.1.15\\\\GitRepositories\\MyApp
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (branch is currently checked out)
error: failed to push some refs to '\\\\10.30.1.15\\GitRepositories\\MyApp'
```

How can I avoid those error messages?

Comment: For the original question (how to do this over network shares): [GIT clone repo across local file system in windows](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2519933/216074)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try escaping the :

```
 git remote add origin \\\\10.30.1.15\\GitRepositories\\MyApp
```

Or use /:

```
 git remote add origin //10.30.1.15/GitRepositories/MyApp
 # or
 git remote add origin file:///10.30.1.15/GitRepositories/MyApp
```

Regarding the second error (which is *not* addressed in "[GIT clone repo across local file system in windows](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2519933/6309)") regards the nature of the remote repo: you need a **[bare repo](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-on-the-Server-Getting-Git-on-a-Server)**.
Or you need, on that remote repo, to set since Git 2.3:

```
git config receive.denyCurrentBranch updateInstead
```

See "[push to deploy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28262104/6309)".

See also "[Git Fetch Error with UNC](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58245916/6309)", where Git 2.24 (Q4 2019) would now authorize:

```
git remote add origin file://10.30.1.15/GitRepositories/MyApp
```

Comment: thanks works but I am now getting different error. See above.

Comment: @user960567 You need to set a config on your remote repo side: see my edited answer.

Comment: It works Thanks you very much

Comment: @user960567 Well done!