# Git clone/pull issues from server

Tags: linux, windows, git, ssh, server

I have a slightly complex issue that can be split across two work environments:

1. My Windows 10 work computer
2. A Linux server, accessible via SSH, VNC and networked SAMBA drive using a VPN

There are two git repos on the server:

1. An archived, shared repo, located at //xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/repos/git-matlab/
2. My personal repo, located at //xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/my-username/repos/personal-repo/

I have set up my SSH keys on both systems (they are present in ~/.ssh).

I have been able to push, pull and clone to personal-repo from my Windows machine without any issues.

When attempting to clone to git-matlab from my Windows machine, I get the following error:

```
$ git clone --branch=main //xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/repos/git-matlab/
Cloning into 'git-matlab'...
error: refs/heads/main does not point to a valid object!
fatal: Remote branch main not found in upstream origin
```

When attempting to clone to git-matlab from personal Linux environment on the server using PuTTY, I get a large error. Output is summarised as follows:

```
$ git clone --branch=main /home/repos/git-matlab/

...

warning: failed to stat /home/repos/git-matlab/.git/objects/a5/1396ecd11cf0fd93cedd0dff1deda885508e3d

warning: failed to stat /home/repos/git-matlab/.git/objects/a5/f60d21cf9955ab0b6c82c12fefaa9e1f51dfc0

warning: failed to stat /home/repos/git-matlab/.git/objects/f3/.

warning: failed to stat /home/repos/git-matlab/.git/objects/f3/..

warning: failed to stat /home/repos/git-matlab/.git/objects/f3/4fd030aeee62a14e915e1fe06d2a7a22e2595e

warning: failed to stat /home/repos/git-matlab/.git/objects/f9/.

warning: failed to stat /home/repos/git-matlab/.git/objects/f9/..

warning: failed to stat /home/repos/git-matlab/.git/objects/f9/7e571b07827b8e32be70c38191cae18e3295b9

done.
```

A git-matlab folder with a .git directory inside does get outputted but that's it.

I should add that these are both shared repos. I also have permissions to view the git-matlab directory via Windows Explorer and Nautilus (Linux file explorer).

Any help or insight would be hugely appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your Git repo `//xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/repos/git-matlab/` seems to be a SAMBA share. In this case SSH keys are not relevant to using Git. I don't know if Git can correctly handle concurrent access to a shared repo in this setup. You might also run into problems when both Git clients running on Linux and those running on Windows access the same repo. I recommend to set up a proper Git server with SSH access. Please [edit] your question and show a non-recursive directory listing of `//xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/repos/git-matlab/` and `/home/repos/git-matlab/.git/` Show the exact command you used on Linux.

Comment: It is a SAMBA drive, yes. It's just wierd that I'm able to clone to and interact with 'personal-repo' from my Windows machine if that's on the same server. 

Thanks for your other comments - I'll certainly be keeping those in mind. I made the edits as requested.

Comment: The warnings `warning: failed to stat /home/repos/git-matlab/.git/objects/...` might result from another process modifying the repository at the same time. I don't know if Git can handle this when using a shared folder. This may depend on the network protocol used for sharing the data. Just another remark: For a shared repository you should use a bare repository which would normally have Git's internal files in `/home/repos/git-matlab.git/` instead of `/home/repos/git-matlab/.git/`.

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure to use the [latest Git For Windows](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases), considering the [support for UNC path was improved](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58245916/6309) in Q4 2019.

Second, if the server is accessible through SSH, then try that protocol

```
git clone ssh://remoteUSer@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/full/path/to/repo
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Sadly, I get the exact same error after authenticating with my password