# Git will escape the backslash on my remote path for Network

Tags: git

This will not work because Git will escape the double backslash into one backslash and it will throw and error that **\MyTestServer\c$\Repository\TestProject** is not a valid repository..

```
git remote add -m master TestServer "\\MyTestServer\c$\Repository\TestProject"

git fetch TestServer
```

Any help please..

Answer (score 2):

You can try [using forward slashes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5432188/6309)

```
git remote add -m master TestServer "//MyTestServer/c$/Repository/TestProject"
```

An older fix was to [try and double-escape the slashes](https://code.google.com/p/msysgit/issues/detail?id=351#c16):

```
git remote add -m master TestServer "\\\\MyTestServer\\c$\\Repository\\TestProject"
```

Answer (score 0):

Note: Git 2.14 (Q3 2017) will make Git more robust when using paths with backslash.
It makes sure that "`foo\bar\baz`" in "`git fetch foo\bar\baz`", even though there is no slashes in it, cannot be a nickname (as in `git remote` name) for a remote on Windows, as that is likely to be a pathname on a local filesystem.

See [commit d9244ec](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d9244ecf4f109030e61b8fd52a799789133e2199) (25 May 2017), and [commit e20b5b5](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e20b5b59099a960d59f20276ae37353870e714de) (22 May 2017) by [Johannes Sixt (`j6t`)](https://github.com/j6t).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 7d26aa3](https://github.com/git/git/commit/7d26aa32309a2a5979c4ae4b85b25b20e8aae0d4), 02 Jun 2017)</sup>

> ### Windows: do not treat a path with backslashes as a remote's nick name
>
> On Windows, the remote repository name in, e.g., `git fetch foo\bar`
>   is clearly not a nickname for a configured remote repository.
>   However, the [function `valid_remote_nick()`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/d9244ecf4f109030e61b8fd52a799789133e2199/remote.c#L644-L654) does not account for backslashes.
>   Use `is_dir_sep()` to check for both slashes and backslashes on Windows.
>
> This was discovered while playing with Duy's patches that warn after
>   `fopen()` failures.
>   The functions that read the branches and remotes
>   files are protected by a `valid_remote_nick()` check.
>   **Without this change, a Windows style absolute path is incorrectly regarded as
>   nickname and is concatenated to a prefix** and used with `fopen()`.
>   This triggers warnings because a colon in a path name is not allowed:

```
C:\Temp\gittest>git fetch C:\Temp\gittest
warning: unable to access '.git/remotes/C:\Temp\gittest': Invalid argument
warning: unable to access '.git/branches/C:\Temp\gittest': Invalid argument
From C:\Temp\gittest
 * branch            HEAD       -> FETCH_HEAD
```