# Git init with symlinks

Tags: windows, git, docker, bitbucket, symlink

I am attempting to run Atlassian BitKeeper within the context of a Docker container (Windows Nano). The home directory is stored outside the context of the container. As a result, this is presented as a symlink inside it.

Running `git init` with the repository contained in the symlink'ed directory results in an error:

```
Invalid path '/ContainerMappedDirectories': No such file or directory.
```

This is the root directory listing portion with respect to the symlink:

```
03/09/2017  02:22 PM    <SYMLINKD>     host [\\?\ContainerMappedDirectories\06928B3D-65E2-4BA6-AADB-7851FD273002]
```

Answer (score 3):

I am suffering the same issue running Jenkins (which uses Git) inside a Docker container. This used to work for me but it stopped after some Git update so I compared few version and I noticed that last version that worked inside a container was 2.11.1.

Here is the proof - C:\temp is mounted from docker host:

```
06/06/2017  04:44 PM    <SYMLINKD>     temp [\\?\ContainerMappedDirectories\3090B08B-4EA2-49CB-8C30-227E982EC311]
```

Attempt with 2.11.1:

```
PS C:\Program Files\git\bin> .\git.exe --version
git version 2.11.1.windows.1
PS C:\Program Files\git\bin> .\git.exe init C:\temp\git11.1\
Initialized empty Git repository in C:/temp/git11.1/.git/
```

Attempt with 2.12.1:

```
PS C:\Program Files\Git\bin> .\git.exe --version
git version 2.12.1.windows.1
PS C:\Program Files\Git\bin> .\git.exe init C:\temp\git12.1\
fatal: Invalid path '/ContainerMappedDirectories': No such file or directory
```

Same with MinGit:

```
PS C:\> .\Min\MinGit-2.13.0-64-bit\cmd\git.exe init C:\temp\MinGitRepo\
fatal: Invalid path '/ContainerMappedDirectories': No such file or directory

PS C:\> .\Min\MinGit-2.11.1-64-bit\cmd\git.exe init C:\temp\MinGitRepo\
Initialized empty Git repository in C:/temp/MinGitRepo/.git/
```

Hard to say what changed, I'll take a deep dive into Git changelog, as for now using 2.11.1 seems like a decent workaround for me. Let me know if it worked for you.

Comment: Maybe Git 2.14 will fix that: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44351381/6309

Comment: no it did not. installed 2.14.1 still having the same issue